# nav bar fixed position and how it affects other elements positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix a nav bar to the top of a page. I have successfully made my nav bar "fixed" but because fixed position jumps out of the normal flow of the document, the content I have positioned underneath it, is now too far up, essentially behind the nav bar, instead of the start being somewhat centered under the nav bar.

Ideally, I'd like the nav bar to fix to the very top of the page after beginning to scroll past the header...but I'm not sure this is possible with just html/css. (I only know a little JS at this point) Essentially, I am most wondering how I can regain control of positioning my content underneath the nav bar (not behind it).

```
<h1 class="name-header">Lacy Roe Recipes</h1>


<nav class="header-wrapper">
    <ul class= "header-nav">
        <li>
            <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-nav-link-dropdown">
            <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Recipes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Cookbooks</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=# class="header-nav-link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Work With Me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=# class="header-nav-link" class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><input type="text" class="search-area"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
<div class="feature-recipe-div">
    <div class="feature-paragraph-div">
        <h2 class="feature-recipe-header">New Lunch Classics</h2>
        <p class="feature-recipe-talk">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe facilis, iure sed quo, expedita nam voluptates consequatur eius vero omnis accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci quibusdam voluptatem facilis aut cumque consequuntur fugiat dicta, praesentium sapiente mollitia in nobis dolorum voluptates iste, laboriosam porro saepe maiores vitae. </p>
        <p><a href="#" class="feature-recipe-link">Continue Reading</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-img-div">
        <img class="main-img" src="https://greenkitchenstories.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Breakfast_bowl_2.jpg">
        <p class="cite">Photograph by David Frankel</p>
    </div>
</div>

.full-page-div{
width:90%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.name-header{
font-family:'Raleway';
font-size:25px;
color:grey;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom:80px;
}

.feature-recipe-div{
display:flex;
width:100%;
justify-content: space-between;
margin-bottom:80px;
z-index:1;
}

.feature-paragraph-div{
width:55%;
}

.feature-recipe-talk, .feature-recipe-link{
font-family:'Cormorant';
font-size: 18px;
}

.feature-recipe-link{
color:grey;
}

.feature-recipe-header{
text-align: center;
font-family:'Raleway';
font-size:50px;
color:black;
font-weight:400;
}

.header-wrapper{
position: fixed;
position: top;
z-index:10;
width:90%;
background-color: white;
}

.header-nav{
display:flex;
list-style:none;
justify-content:space-evenly;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-bottom:50px;
z-index:10;
}

.header-nav-link{
text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Raleway';
text-transform: uppercase;
color: grey;
}
```

Comment: You can just add a wrapper for everything else and add `position: absolute; top: 100px;` or whatever `top`.

Comment: You mean a wrapper for all the content that is beneath, position it absolute?

Comment: have you tried `position: sticky;` already? thats exactly what position sticky is for.

Comment: Yeah everything that isn't part of the navbar

Comment: I just tried absolute, but it makes my section jump out of the flow I created, and everything is on top of each other

Comment: Sticky doesn't seem to work for some reason

Comment: because you usign invalid css. `position: top;` is a wrong css value and therefor invalid. `position` values are: `static, absolute, fixed, relative, sticky, intial, inherit`. The positioninign has to be done with the attributes: `top, bottom, left, right` followed by a value with a relative or absolute measurement.

Comment: Yes, I did remove position:top, I wasn't thinking, but it still doesn't work on sticky

Comment: I'll go work on this, thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `position: sticky;` combined with `top: 0;` and it will work as intended. your main issue is following css line:

> .header-wrapper{
> position: fixed;
> position: top;
> z-index:10;
> width:90%;
> }

its invalid css as you first declare `position: fixed;` and right after `position: top;` which is invalid and overwriets the first. What you actually mean is `top: 0;`

background-color: white; }

```css
.full-page-div {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.name-header {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 25px;
  color: grey;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.feature-recipe-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feature-paragraph-div {
  width: 55%;
}

.feature-recipe-talk,
.feature-recipe-link {
  font-family: 'Cormorant';
  font-size: 18px;
}

.feature-recipe-link {
  color: grey;
}

.feature-recipe-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="name-header">Lacy Roe Recipes</h1>


<nav class="header-wrapper">
  <ul class="header-nav">
    <li>
      <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="header-nav-link-dropdown">
      <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Recipes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Cookbooks</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=# class="header-nav-link">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Work With Me</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=# class="header-nav-link">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=# class="header-nav-link" class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><input type="text" class="search-area"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="feature-recipe-div">
  <div class="feature-paragraph-div">
    <h2 class="feature-recipe-header">New Lunch Classics</h2>
    <p class="feature-recipe-talk">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe facilis, iure sed quo, expedita nam voluptates consequatur eius vero omnis accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci quibusdam voluptatem facilis
      aut cumque consequuntur fugiat dicta, praesentium sapiente mollitia in nobis dolorum voluptates iste, laboriosam porro saepe maiores vitae. </p>
    <p><a href="#" class="feature-recipe-link">Continue Reading</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="main-img-div">
    <img class="main-img" src="https://greenkitchenstories.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Breakfast_bowl_2.jpg">
    <p class="cite">Photograph by David Frankel</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it to work!! Thank you!! How do I add the "run code snippet to my questions?

Comment: there is a button for it on top of the editor. Alternativly press `Ctrl + M`.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to fix.

Just add `margin-top` to a div that holds the content that you want to move.

For example :

```
.someDiv{
    margin-top : 15%;
}
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Any ideas why sticky isn't working but fixed is?

Comment: see my latest comment: because you used invalid css declaration. If you run my snippet, you'll see that sticky runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Amazing ! :) Vote me up if that's all.